# How can i get sentence instead of word? i want to search second string in first string by strstr in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to search for a second string in a first string, by get strings from the user. But `cin` doesn't work for sentences because of spaces. How can I get a string as a sentence and then search for a second string in that sentence?

```cpp
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str;
    cin>>str;
    string target;
    cin>>target
    char *p = strstr(str, target);

    if (p)
        cout << "'" << target << "' is present in \"" << str << "\" at position " << p-str;
    else
        cout << target << " is not present \"" << str << "\"";

    return 0;
}
```

https://onlinegdb.com/S1IVrTVHO

Comment: Be aware that a sentence can span multiple lines.

Comment: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/8746648)

Answer (score 1):

> But `cin` doesn't work for sentences because of spaces.

`std::cin` is not the one that cares about spaces, `operator>>` does.  Simply use [`std::getline(cin,str)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead of `cin >> str` when reading the sentence.

Also, you should be using [`std::string::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) instead of `strstr()`.

Try this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str;
    getline(cin, str);

    string target;
    cin >> target;

    string::size_type p = str.find(target);
    if (p != string::npos)
        cout << "'" << target << "' is present in \"" << str << "\" at position " << p;
    else
        cout << "'" << target << "' is not present in \"" << str << "\"";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a whole line, use `getline()` which is in `<string>`.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str;
    getline(cin, str);
    string target;
    getline(cin, target);
    const char* p = strstr(str.c_str(), target.c_str());
    if (p)
        cout << "'" << target << "' is present in \"" << str << "\" at position " << p - str.c_str();
    else
        cout << target << " is not present \"" << str << "\"";

    return 0;
}
```

The `.c_str` convert the `std::string` to a C-Style string, so that `strstr`, which only takes C-Style strings, can do it's operations. Also, in your original code, you forgot to terminate `cin>>target` with a `;`.

`std::cin` is where the input comes from. The `>>` operator gets something from `std::cin` until a whitespace. If you want a whole line, use `std::getline(cin, str)` instead of `cin >> str`. `std::getline()` reads from `std::cin` until it hits a newline, so it is better for your purposes. (`std::getline` takes a `istream` (like `std::cin`) as its first parameter, and a `std::string` to put its result as it's second parameter.)

Also, in the future, you might consider using other methods of finding strings in strings, and not use `strstr()`, as that is for C-Style strings, and for more C++ style substring finding, there may be better alternatives.

Bye!

Comment: what is the best alternatives ?

Comment: std::string::find probably, but there are others also